# Accessing & Manipulating Azure AD B2C Users via Web Application

Tags: python, flask, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I'm struggling with basic user management while working with Azure's AD B2C framework.

I've successfully set up an Azure AD B2C resource, registered my consumer-facing web application (created a client secret and granted permission, both delegated and application, to User.ReadWrite.All), created custom attributes, and added out-of-the-box signup and signin user flows. Furthermore, I've successfully registered and signed-in users to my web application.

To get to this point, I followed the Python sample provided within the documentation (ms-identity-python-webapp-master):

**app.py**

```
@app.route("/login")
def login():
    session["state"] = str(uuid.uuid4())
    # Technically we could use empty list [] as scopes to do just sign in,
    # here we choose to also collect end user consent upfront
    auth_url = _build_auth_url(scopes=app_config_b2c.SCOPE, state=session["state"])
    return render_template("templates/login.html", auth_url=auth_url, version=msal.__version__)

@app.route(app_config_b2c.REDIRECT_PATH)  # Its absolute URL must match your app's redirect_uri set in AAD
def authorized():
    if request.args.get('state') != session.get("state"):
        return redirect(url_for("index"))  # No-OP. Goes back to Index page
    if "error" in request.args:  # Authentication/Authorization failure
        return render_template("auth_error.html", result=request.args)
    if request.args.get('code'):
        cache = _load_cache()
        result = _build_msal_app(cache=cache).acquire_token_by_authorization_code(
            request.args['code'],
            scopes=app_config_b2c.SCOPE,  # Misspelled scope would cause an HTTP 400 error here
            redirect_uri=url_for("authorized", _external=True))
        if "error" in result:
            return render_template("auth_error.html", result=result)
        session["user"] = result.get("id_token_claims")
        _save_cache(cache)
    return redirect(url_for("index"))

@app.route("/logout")
def logout():
    session.clear()  # Wipe out user and its token cache from session
    return redirect(  # Also logout from your tenant's web session
        app_config_b2c.AUTHORITY + "/oauth2/v2.0/logout" +
        "?post_logout_redirect_uri=" + url_for("index", _external=True))

@app.route("/graphcall")
def graphcall():
    token = _get_token_from_cache(app_config_b2c.SCOPE)
    if not token:
        return redirect(url_for("login"))
    graph_data = requests.get(  # Use token to call downstream service
        app_config_b2c.ENDPOINT,
        headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token['access_token']},
        ).json()
    return render_template('templates/display.html', result=graph_data)


def _load_cache():
    cache = msal.SerializableTokenCache()
    if session.get("token_cache"):
        cache.deserialize(session["token_cache"])
    return cache

def _save_cache(cache):
    if cache.has_state_changed:
        session["token_cache"] = cache.serialize()

def _build_msal_app(cache=None, authority=None):
    return msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
        app_config_b2c.CLIENT_ID, authority=authority or app_config_b2c.AUTHORITY,
        client_credential=app_config_b2c.CLIENT_SECRET, token_cache=cache)

def _build_auth_url(authority=None, scopes=None, state=None):
    return _build_msal_app(authority=authority).get_authorization_request_url(
        scopes or [],
        state=state or str(uuid.uuid4()),
        redirect_uri=url_for("authorized", _external=True))

def _get_token_from_cache(scope=None):
    cache = _load_cache()  # This web app maintains one cache per session
    cca = _build_msal_app(cache=cache)
    accounts = cca.get_accounts()
    if accounts:  # So all account(s) belong to the current signed-in user
        result = cca.acquire_token_silent(scope, account=accounts[0])
        _save_cache(cache)
        return result
```

**app_config_b2c.py**

```
import os

b2c_tenant = "myapplication"
signupsignin_user_flow = "b2c_1_signupsignin1"
editprofile_user_flow = "b2c_1_profileediting1"
resetpassword_user_flow = "b2c_1_passwordreset1"
authority_template = "https://{tenant}.b2clogin.com/{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/{user_flow}"

CLIENT_SECRET = "Enter_the_Client_Secret_Here" # Our Quickstart uses this placeholder
# In your production app, we recommend you to use other ways to store your secret,
# such as KeyVault, or environment variable as described in Flask's documentation here
# https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/config/#configuring-from-environment-variables
# CLIENT_SECRET = os.getenv("CLIENT_SECRET")
# if not CLIENT_SECRET:
#     raise ValueError("Need to define CLIENT_SECRET environment variable")

AUTHORITY = authority_template.format(
    tenant=b2c_tenant, user_flow=signupsignin_user_flow)
B2C_PROFILE_AUTHORITY = authority_template.format(
    tenant=b2c_tenant, user_flow=editprofile_user_flow)
B2C_RESET_PASSWORD_AUTHORITY = authority_template.format(
    tenant=b2c_tenant, user_flow=resetpassword_user_flow)

CLIENT_ID = "xxx.xxxxxx"

REDIRECT_PATH = "/getAToken"  # It will be used to form an absolute URL
    # And that absolute URL must match your app's redirect_uri set in AAD

# This is the resource that you are going to access in your B2C tenant
ENDPOINT = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users'

# These are the scopes that you defined for the web API
SCOPE = ["User.ReadWrite.All"]

SESSION_TYPE = "filesystem"  # So token cache will be stored in server-side session
```

The graphcall doesn't work within this framework (perhaps it's a b2c issue), which I'm sure is part of the problem, but ultimately I'd just like the application to consume the logged-in user's AD attributes (particularly the custom attributes I've enabled), and modify them when necessary. For instance, say a custom attribute is "paid_subscriber". When a user registers, the attribute is empty. When the user purchases content, I'd like to set the value of the attribute to something relevant (like "true").

Is this possible? Do I need other user flows? What am I missing here (theoretically and practically)?

Comment: Hi. Microsoft graph is projected by Azure AD. So if we want to call Microsoft graph, we need to do Azure AD auth. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/microsoft-graph-get-started?tabs=applications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft Graph does not support the tokens issued by the Azure AD B2C. 
You need to have the access token generated by the Azure AD.

There is a process using Azure ad b2c custom policy where you can integrated the Microsoft Graph and add custom attributes to the claims.

This [document](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/B2C-Token-Includes-AzureAD-BearerToken) helps you to get the Azure AD access token to call Graph, With the above implementation there wont be much changes in the phython code

for adding the custom attributes go through the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-custom-attributes)